# Mysql 5.6 doesn't want to set a column to NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-5.5

I am about 98% sure this query has been working properly on mysql 5.1. We have upgraded one of our machines to mysql 5.6 and I am running an update and its getting a database error with this query:

```sql
 UPDATE diagnostic 
    LEFT JOIN contact ON diagnosticdata_suppliercontact = contact_id
    SET diagnosticdata_suppliercontact = NULL
    WHERE (!contactdata_issupplier) OR (contact.contact_id IS NULL);
```

However the table schema allows it to be NULL. Does anyone know of any problems or changes that happened in mysql 5.6 that could cause us grief?

Here is a description of the table:

```
mysql> describe diagnostic;
+--------------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| diagnostic_id                  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| diagnostic_time                | int(15)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| diagnostic_user                | int(15)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| diagnosticdata_time            | int(15)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| diagnosticdata_user            | int(15)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| diagnosticdata_name            | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| diagnosticdata_suppliercontact | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'diagnosticdata_suppliercontact' cannot be null
```

CREATE STATEMENT IS HERE TO there are triggers:

```sql
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `diagnostic` (
  `diagnostic_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `diagnostic_time` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `diagnostic_user` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `diagnosticdata_time` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `diagnosticdata_user` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `diagnosticdata_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `diagnosticdata_suppliercontact` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`diagnostic_id`),
  KEY `diagnostic_suppliercontact` (`diagnosticdata_suppliercontact`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_diagnosticdata_suppliercontact_contact` FOREIGN KEY (`diagnosticdata_suppliercontact`) REFERENCES `contact` (`contact_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=188 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`dotuser`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `ezymerged`.`diagnostic_insert`
AFTER INSERT ON `ezymerged`.`diagnostic`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    REPLACE INTO  ezymerged_history.diagnostic 
     SELECT diagnostic.* FROM ezymerged.diagnostic 
      WHERE diagnostic_id=NEW.diagnostic_id;                    
END
$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`dotuser`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `ezymerged`.`diagnostic_update`
AFTER UPDATE ON `ezymerged`.`diagnostic`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    REPLACE INTO  ezymerged_history.diagnostic 
     SELECT diagnostic.* FROM ezymerged.diagnostic 
      WHERE diagnostic_id=NEW.diagnostic_id;                    
END
$$
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Sorry just updated it with the error.

Comment: Basically I am doing a left join. If it fails to join on the contact, then the contact table columns will be NULL. 
You can use !columnname that column contactdata_supplier is an int, and in this case i am looking for records where the value is not a 0. 
e.g. This is valid SQL: 
select * from contact where !contactdata_issupplier;

Comment: @Chris, Mark: In MySQL dialect, the `(!contactdata_issupplier)` is equivalent to `(NOT contactdata_issupplier)` which is equivalent to `(contactdata_issupplier IS FALSE)` which (for int columns) is also equivalent to: `(contactdata_issupplier = 0)`

Comment: Please add the `CREATE TABLE` statement. Are there triggers on the table?

Comment: I have added the create statement with the trigger.

Comment: So, probably the `ezymerged_history.diagnostic.diagnosticdata_suppliercontact` column is not nullable. Or something went wrong with your upgrade.

Comment: Yeh thanks heaps. You are correct, The ezymerged_history.diagnostic.diagnosticdata_suppliercontact is marked as NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

While the `diagnosticdata_suppliercontact` allows for `NULL`s the constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_diagnosticdata_suppliercontact_contact`
FOREIGN KEY (`diagnosticdata_suppliercontact`)
REFERENCES `contact` (`contact_id`)
```

will take precedence, and requires the value in `diagnosticdata_suppliercontact` to have a matching value in the `contact_id` field in the `contact` table.